# Matlab How to receive color name after inputting RGB values

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, rgb, pixel

Matlab: How to receive color name after inputting RGB values

So I have this image and I used impixelregion to find the RGB values of each pixel. However, I want the name of the color to show up on Matlab. For example, if I input RGB values [9,9,11], I want Matlab to tell me that the color is black. Do I have to create my own function or code for this or is there something out there that can let me input whatever RGB values I want and have Matlab tell me what color those RGB values stand for?

thank you!

Comment: you can use websites like these: http://gauth.fr/2011/09/get-a-color-name-from-any-rgb-combination/ ,  http://www.color-blindness.com/color-name-hue/ or write you own function in matlab...

Comment: you are talking about 16.7 **million** different combinations. No language on earth has so many words, so you will have to group them by categories (as they do in the example given in natan's comment above). There is no Matlab built-in function that do that at the moment, you will have to write your own function. Basically define a table with as many _named_ color you desire, each with a given RGB value, then for each RGB combination you want to name, find the closest match in the table and return the corresponding name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a file with the name and corresponding color value, following [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors:_A%E2%80%93F):

[Colors_name_val.mat](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49778147/forum/Colors_name_val.mat)

And here is the corresponding code to give you the name of a color.

```
function name = name_rgb(my_val)

   load('Colors_name_val.mat')

   delta=10000000;

   for k=1:430
       curDelta=sum(abs(my_val-Val(k,:)));

       if(curDelta<delta)
           name=Name(k);
           delta=curDelta;
        end
   end
end
```

It just find the less different color of the list, by minimising `sum(abs(my_val-Val(k,:)))`